# Unlink file in the sub folder

Tags: php, unlink

I have a problem to unlink my file in the subfolder. I want to delete the wonderful.pdf in the Test3 subfolder.Below is my coding:

```html
<?php
$delete_file =  Test/Test2/Test3/wonderful.pdf;

unlink($delete_file);

?>
```

The result no response to delete the file. Hope someone can guide me how to unlink the file in the subfolder. Thanks.

Comment: is your code file in the same folder as of that pdf file?

Comment: yes, same pdf file

Comment: put path inside qoutes and test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getcwd()` function to get the current working directory. Manual: [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

```
<?php
//Your project location like an example in Unix 
// /var/www/Test/Test2/Test3/wonderful.pdf
// then you $subfolder var will get this: Test2/Test3
$filename = 'wonderful.pdf';
$subfolder = 'Test3';
$delete_file =  getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $subfolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

unlink($delete_file);

?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. in my real scenario Test/Test2/Test3/ is a variable. Can put folder location variable in your code?

Comment: For example:  $folder location = 'Test/Test2/Test3';

Comment: If this folders are sub folders in the current folder you can use this script.

Comment: To delete file you have to get full path to this file.

Comment: if this is full path of this file Test/Test2/Test3/wonderful.pdf, can use your code to delete file right. Because Test/Test2/Test3/wonderful.pdf this will become the variable in my side, because I grab from database to delete a file

Comment: Full path will be in Unix sistems: `/var/www/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/Test/Test2/Test3/wonderful.pdf`, Like i understand you have a relative path in hands with a `Test` like a root folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

As your PDF file is in the same folder as that of your code file you must only specify the pdf file name and not the whole path from start.

```
<?php
$delete_file = wonderful.pdf;

unlink($delete_file);

?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php you can refer this too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to delete Test/Test2/Test3/wonderful.pdf, if your code detect my other folder location example like A/B/C/wonderful.pdf. It will also delete right?